# Handling lack of permissions/groups with pathlib's rglob

Tags: python, permissions, pathlib

I am attempting to use pathlib to recursively glob and/or find files. File permissions and groups are all over the place due to poor management of the filesystem which is out of my control.

The problem occurs when I lack both permissions and group membership to a directory that rglob attempts to descend into. Rglob throws a KeyError and then a PermissionError and finally stops entirely. I see no way to recover gracefully from this and continue globbing.

The behavior that I want is for rglob to skip directories that I don't have permissions on and to generate the list of everything that it saw/had permissions on. The all or nothing nature isn't going to get me very far in this particular case because I'm almost guaranteed to have bad permissions on some directory or another on every run.

More specifics:

Python: 3.4.1 compiled from source for linux

Filesystem I am globbing on: automounted nfs share

How to reproduce:

```
mkdir /tmp/path_test && cd /tmp/path_test && mkdir dir1 dir2 dir2/dir3 && touch dir1/file1 dir1/file2 dir2/file1 dir2/file2 dir2/dir3/file1
su
chmod 700 dir2/dir3/
chown root:root dir2/dir3/
exit
```

python3.4.1

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/tmp/path_test')
for x in p.rglob('*') : print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

At first I tried to manually iterate though the results of `rglob()` like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/tmp/path_test')
files = p.rglob('*')
while True:
    try:
        f = next(files)
    except (KeyError, PermissionError):
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(f)
```

But it looks like `next(files)` throws a `StopIteration` after the first `PermissionError`, so I don't get any files after that.

You may be better off using [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk).